# Each other vs. one another

Tags: expression-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “each other” vs. “one another”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5914/when-should-i-use-each-other-vs-one-another)

It occurred to me recently that I've been using these phrases interchangeably (basing my decision purely on how formal I want to sound).  Are they really interchangeable?

What's the appropriate usage in:

"Human beings often fail to understand what's most important to [___]..."

Is it "one another", "each other", either, or neither?

Comment: @MetaEd: Given that OP considers the third possibility *"neither"*, I don't think this is a dup of that straightforward either/or.

Answer (score 3):

The standard rule is:

1. Use "each other" to refer to two entities that are exchanging something.
2. Prefer "one another" when there are three or more in question.

Answer (score 1):

Neither usage is appropriate. Without context, I have no idea what this *"most important"* thing is (perhaps, as the statement implies, simply because I'm a human being).

It would be perfectly reasonable to end the sentence at the word *"important"*. Semantically (but not stylistically) it could reasonably end with *"to human beings"* as far as I'm concerned, but someone else might say it should end with *"to God's plan", "to world peace"* or just about anything the writer thinks is important, but which he thinks others don't "get".

EDIT: Thanks to @RegDwight for pointing out an obvious interpretation of what's most important that I simply failed to spot. If what a person (i.e. - people in general) fails to understand is what's important *to another person or to other people*, the form should be...

> Human beings often fail to understand what's most important to others.

Comment: I think what the OP is trying to say is that humans fail to understand what's important *to other humans*. Mutual misunderstanding, so to speak.

Comment: @RegDwight: oic. I never thought of it that way. I'd better edit to reflect, ty.