# word usage 'understand each other'

Tags: differences, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Each other” vs. “one another”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5914/each-other-vs-one-another)

Those using Irish Sign Language, American Sign Language or British Sign Language, will not automatically understand one another.

or

Those using Irish Sign Language, American Sign Language or British Sign Language, will not automatically understand each other.

which one is correct?

Comment: They're both fine - no difference in meaning, but *each other* is more common. Maybe some people might think *one another* is more "formal", but I don't.

Answer (score 0):

They both mean the same thing and are both equally correct!